# Can I return the value of document.getelementbyid inside a document.setcookie?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

```
<input type=button value='Do Stuff' onClick='document.cookie = "Note_<% Response.Write(arrTest(0,i)) %> = ' + (Document.getElementById("StuffTest<% Response.Write(arrTest(0,i)) %>").value) + '"'>
```

What I'm trying to do here is when the user hits the button, I want a cookie created with the values: Note_(value of arrTest) = (Value of the text box).

The code below works just fine:

```
<input type=button value='Do Stuff' onClick='document.cookie = "Note_<% Response.Write(arrTest(0,i)) %> = Awesome!"'>
```

It creates a cookie with the value of: Note_(value of arrTest) = Awesome!

What have I done wrong to get the value of my text box into the cookie?  I'm assuming it has to do with all those confusing single/double quotes, so I think I've just got typo-blindness, but part of me thinks I can't actually do what I'm trying to do here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById` has `document` in all lower case. Your code example uses `Document` (with a capital `D`), which will fail.

Separately, your quotes such in the `onClick` attribute are not quite right. It's best to avoid putting any significant code in those attributes. Instead, define and call a function, like this:

```
<input type=button
       value='Do Stuff'
       onClick='setCookie("<% Response.Write(arrTest(0,i)) %>);'>
```

...where the function (inside a `<script>` tag or in a file referenced by one) looks like this:

```
function setCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = "Name_" + name + "=" + document.getElementById("StuffTest" + name).value;
}
```

Depending on the contents of `arrTest(0,i)`, you might need to HTML-encode it as you output it, since you're outputting it to HTML (yes, the code inside an `onXYZ` attribute is HTML, just like any other attribute's value, so for instance `<` would need to be `&lt;`).

Comment: I actually had a function originally, but I keep getting an error about the function not being defined.  Thought this way might be easier.  I guess not.  Oh well, back to the drawing board.

Comment: Never mind... It was a giant brain fart (the 'not being defined error').  Who's the (wo)man?  You're the (wo)man!

Comment: @JGGR13: Glad that helped. *"Who's the (wo)man? You're the (wo)man!"* LOL!